# Redirect from example.com/de/ to example.com

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to change the domain link from:
 example.com/de/ to example.com

This is what I have been doing but with no success:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The .htaccess file is located in the root of my project, thank you and any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to do the redirect in PHP?

Comment: yes my project is written in php

Comment: That was not my question. I see you have posted htaccess file and yet you tagged PHP, so which is it? PHP or htaccess?

Comment: sorry, i am in need of the proper solution in htaccess. @anubhava that didnt work i still get the /de/ redirect

Comment: Do you have a directory /de exisiting? If yes, then the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule would prevent a rewrite

Comment: yes i have my whole project pages and other assets located inside the de directory, should i comment in or out the rewriteCond?

Comment: yes right in the root of the project

Comment: that is the full htaccess i have nothing else

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: yes it shows the 500 error, i also am abit familiar with .htaccess so i know if its enabled or not